# How to overcome mental fatigue after long work?

Tags: sleep

It's a weird and awesome phenomenon I didn't really find [much](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/thinking-hard-calories/) on: Even though our brains burn (probably) as much calories when hard working as when we just hang out, we somehow feel "mentally" tired when we have to think for a long time.

I'd guess it has something to do with how the neuron signals get messy after a while and we have to take a nap.

Is there a way to avoid it?